# How can get data from firestore when I need to filter the country?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How can get data from Firestore when I need to filter the country?

Before I'd used the Realtime Database, but now I need to change to use Firestore.

In my Realtime Database code, it would check the country:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        Query query = reference.orderByChild("country").equalTo(country);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                postLists.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    PostModel post = snapshot.getValue(PostModel.class);
                    postLists.add(post);
                }

                postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

but if I wanna change to use Firestore, how can I do it?

I use this code, I will get an error. `'com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

```
db.collection("Posts").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> list  = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot d : list){
                        PostModel post = d.toObject(PostModel.class);
                        postLists.add(post);
                    }
                    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data found in Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Which line of code is the error on?  What exactly is `db`?  Please edit the question to provide a [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also useful if you show what your database looks like, but you might want to read about Firestore [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) on collections.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry about it, I foegot add db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
And how do I can filter country?

Comment: @TylerV Sorry about it,  I foegot add db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(); And I cannot use this way =>  .whereEqualTo(country, true).get() Because my country is dynamic. how could I use it? and I updated my context, could you check it?

Comment: I found the answer :)

Comment: Can you please evaluate my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

To search the documents where the "country" field holds the value of a specific country, please change the following line:

```
db.collection("Posts").get().addOnSuccessListener(/* ... /*);
```

Into:

```
db.collection("Posts").whereEqualTo("country", country).get().addOnSuccessListener(/* ... /*);
```